# AngularJS infinite loop when routeParams not null

Tags: angularjs, loops, infinite, routeparams

I'm trying to use the `routeParams` so I can get part of a URL, but it gets me into an infinite loop when I try to access to the URL with a GET parameter. Currently, I have the following defined:

```
var nappet = angular.module('nappet', ['ngRoute', 'ngCookies']);

nappet.config(['$routeProvider', '$locationProvider', function($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
    $routeProvider
        .when('/', {templateUrl: 'app/home/view/homeView.html', controller: 'homeController'})
        .when('/organizadores', {templateUrl: 'app/organizers/view/organizerView.html', controller: 'organizerController'})
        .when('/organizadores/:organizer', {templateUrl: 'app/organizers/view/organizerDetailView.html', controller: 'organizerController'})

    $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
}]);
```

And here's the controller:

```
nappet.controller('organizerController', function($scope, $location, $cookies, $http, $routeParams) {

    if($routeParams.organizer === undefined) {
        console.log('Works');
    } else {
        console.log('Infinite loop');
    }
});
```

So, if I put anything replacing the organizer param, it prints that "Infinite loop" message in a loop, but it works when I don't use any parameter on the URL. What could be the problem here?

Comment: Did you try to add `.otherwise({redirectTo:'/organizadores'});` after the las `when` ?

Comment: order of route declarations is backwards

Comment: @charlietfl changed the order and it still continues

Comment: you could combine those routes into one using a wildcard also

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to add the `.otherwise({redirectTo:'/organizadores'});` instruction to your `$routeProvider`.

Comment: I've got the otherwise pointing to '/error' already, but I removed from the code